# convert Caffe train.txt to Tensorflow

Tags: caffe, tensorflow

I am trying to adapting my Caffe code to tensorflow. I wonder what is the best way to convert my train.txt and test.txt in order to work for tensorflow.

In my train.txt, the file looks like:

```
/folder/filename1.jpg 1

/folder/filename2.jpg 2
...
```

The first column is the image name and the second column is the class label

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to obtain a batch of identically-sized images with numeric labels. We'll use [`tf.decode_csv()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_csv) to parse the text, [`tf.read_file()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#read_file) to load the JPEG data as a string, [`tf.image.decode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_jpeg) to parse it into a dense tensor, and finally [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch) to build the parsed data into a batch of images. Many of these functions have a lot of options to configure, so see the documentation for further customization details.

```py
# Set options here for whether to repeat, etc.
filename_producer = tf.string_input_producer(["train.txt"], ...)

# Read lines from the file, one at a time.
line_reader = tf.TextLineReader()
next_line = line_reader.read(filename_producer)

# Parse line into a filename and an integer label.
image_filename, label = tf.decode_csv(
    next_line, [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string), tf.constant([], dtype=tf.int32)],
    field_delim=" ")

# Read the image as a string.
image_bytes = tf.read_file(image_filename)

# Convert the image into a 3-D tensor (height x width x channels).
image_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_bytes, ...)

# OPTIONAL: Resize your image to a standard size if they are not already.
HEIGHT = ...
WIDTH = ...
image_tensor = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image_tensor, HEIGHT, WIDTH)

# Create a batch of images.
BATCH_SIZE = 32
images, labels = tf.train.batch([image_tensor, label], BATCH_SIZE, ...)

# [...build the rest of your model...]
```

This example makes extensive use of TensorFlow prefetching to load the examples. The TensorFlow documentation has a [how-to that explains how to use the prefetching feature](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html), but the most important thing to note is that you must call `tf.train.start_queue_runners()` at the start of your session to begin prefetching:

```
sess = tf.Session()

# You must execute this statement to begin prefetching data.
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It is very helpful. In you code, you used images, labels = tf.train.batch([image_tensor, label], BATCH_SIZE, ...). I wonder if I need to get the data and label from next batch, should I just call tf.train.batch again with the same arguments or implement my own get_next_batch function. Thanks!!